# Looking for Ember PRE4 minified version, can someone point me to the location where I can find one

Tags: ember.js

I am looking for ember-1.0.0-pre.4.js minified version can someone point me to the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find all of the release builds (min and normal) of Ember here:

https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/tree/release-builds